# HTTP 404 after Sharepoint migration (wss 2 -> wss 3)

Tags: sharepoint, wss-3.0, wss-2.0, sharepoint-upgrade

We upgraded a wss 2 site according to Microsoft standard (prescan, migration etc) and resolved smaller issues on the way.

However, now we don't receive any errors, and when we access the site in wss 3 it gives us a 404 - page not found error. We now there is a site at the root, and wss confirms that...anyone knows what's wrong?

By the way: We also upgraded another site the exact same way and it works beautifully...

Answer (score 0):

What does the log file say?

Is the content database correctly setup? (Name / Server.) More specifically, the permissions for the pool account.